# php display error message and clean content

Tags: php

I want code to display error message, on same time remove page content

EG.

```
<?
echo 'welcome';
if (login==0)
{
    error("you can't access to this page");
}
content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content
ect.......
?>
```

Output

```
you can't access to this page
```

the exemple remove all content but it keep error("you can't access to this page");

Comment: use output buffering: http://en.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 1):

Add `exit();` inside your if statement. Using your example:

```
<?
echo 'welcome';
if (login==0)
{
    error("you can't access to this page");
    exit();
}
content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content
ect.......
?>
```

Comment: Matt Harvey's answer is the simplest solution for this. You might also want to move echo "welcome" after the if(login == "0") condition check so that you do not see a welcome message and then a "you don't have access to this page" message

Comment: I want cleaning all output and keep only "you can't access to this page"

Comment: Yeah, just move `echo 'welcome';` to after the `}` that closes the if statement. Otherwise, you'll need to use Javascript to clear the contents of the page before outputting the error. Also, you can change `error("...");` to simply `echo` the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could use what Matt provides as well, here's another alternative:

```
<?
echo 'welcome';
if(login==0) {
  error("you can't access to this page");
} else {
?>
content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content, content
<?php
}
?>
```